# Preview Transform no longer working for Web.Config after Visual Studio 2017 Update

Tags: web-applications, visual-studio-2017, web-config, config-transformation, xml-document-transform

I had noticed after updating my Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.8.0 the Option to Preview Transformation is no longer working.

**1) Here I am attempting to change it to our QA.config**
[image: Context Menu for Transforming my local web.config.]

**2) Once I click on it after the update, I am receiving the following error message below.**

[image: One of the many helpful errors Microsoft outputs]

I hadn't seen anything online thus far and I would imagine this is because these updates just came out recently and most users have not performed the update yet.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like they're aware and a fix should be ready soon.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/310891/preview-transform-gives-error.html